# Vim on Windows: Mapping control sequences to keys in vimrc doesn't work for insert mode

Tags: windows, vim

I'm running Vim 7.2 on Windows 7, and I'm having issues mapping control sequences in insert mode.

I can use `:inoremap jl <Esc>` while inside vim, and, as expected, typing `jl` while in insert mode will cause vim to go to normal mode. However, if I put `inoremap jl <Esc>` in my _vimrc, then type `jl` inside vim in insert mode, it actually types out `<Esc>`, which is not what I wanted. I've tried variations with backslashes and whatnot, but those just get typed out too.

How can I set up my _vimrc to exit to normal mode when I type `jl` in insert or visual mode?

Comment: It worked for me... `inoremap jl <Esc>` in _vimrc makes it exit insert mode by typing `jl`.  Using a gVim 7.2 (2008 Arg 9, compiled Feb 26 2010 12:56:39), MS-Windows 64-bit GUI version with OLE support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either be in `nocompatible` mode for `<Key>` to work, or explicitely specify `<special>`:

```
inoremap <special> jl <Esc>
```

or

```
set nocompatible " At the very top of vimrc, before any other option
<...>
inoremap jl <Esc>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was part of the problem. Some of the stuff in the "default" _vimrc was causing issues too.